# Android emulator doesn't run the app but there wasn't any error

Tags: android, android-layout

I only added buttons textviews and edittexts to my main.xml on graphical layout. But it doesn't work with emulator and it didn't give any errors? I'd be crazy with that. Here's the code and I also couldn't change the button locations because of that...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Dersin Adı" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Kredi" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Eski Not" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:text="Yeni Not" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ders"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kredi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ders"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ders"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/eskiNot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/kredi"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/kredi"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/yeniNot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/eskiNot"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/eskiNot"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gno"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ders"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ders"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="GNO" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dno"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gno"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gno"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gno"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="DNO" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ekle"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/gno"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gno"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/yeniNot"
    android:text="Ekle" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gnoHesap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ekle"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ekle"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/yeniNot"
    android:text="Gno Hesap"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dnoHesap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gnoHesap"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/yeniNot"
    android:text="Dno Hesap"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `<requestFocus />` tag. Does it exist to be used that way? Also I see no `</RelativeLayout>` at the end of the file.

Comment: </RelativeLayout> is there but i couldnt copy it i guess. I dont know its automatically added(<requestFocus /> tag)

Comment: `requestFocus` is a valid tag. Your LogCat displays nothing when you try to launch? I'm guessing it displays something. Perhaps you aren't monitoring the right thing in LogCat?

Comment: The application xxxx has stopped unexpectly. Please try again. It always gives this error on emulator but it doesnt give any errors on eclipse

Comment: Source code is useful here and also try to get a LogCat stack trace. _stopped unexpectly_ is accompanied by a stack trace.

Comment: XML syntax errors don't always generate warnings / errors via eclipse, especially older versions, and attempting to run can fail silently. Are you using the emulator, a device, or a virtual device?

Comment: Just verified that syntax is valid. Did you create an Activity and assign the layout?

Comment: If you have added only "SetContentView(R.layout.your_xml);" then fine, if you have assigned wrong ids to wrong elements, then your app might get crash on runtime. Can you post your java code.

Comment: If you getting the app force close message in the emulator then there should be an error in logcat. Make sure you haven't enabled any filters that might be hiding the output. Also, during my development I have noticed logcat sometimes seems to lose the emulator and I need to restart both eclipse and the emulator and normally log cat starts working again. Your java code for the activity that uses that layout would be handy to see as well